# custom 404 error page after moving wordpress from one host to other

Tags: wordpress

I own a website say xyz.com using wordpress. I have to transfer the wordpress site + content +everything to a new host..

Make a note that I am not moving to different domain name. I am just changing  my host .

I have copied the sql data wp files n contents to new host.

When I try to open the site in new host I am getting the custom 404 error page .. its not the default 404 page its the custom one so I guess the wordpress is fine. all the links are directed to my old host because I have not changed my domain name to new host. I planned to make the dns change once the new host Works fine...

What is the reason for the custom 404 page ? How to resolve. ?

Comment: How are you testing this new host? If you haven't changed the domain DNS settings, I am guessing you perhaps setup a subdomain for testing?

Comment: How are you accessing it at the new host if not by domain name?  Do you have something like http://someipaddress/~someusername

Comment: its not sub domain...i am accessing bu ipaddress/`username ,like pete said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reesetting your permalinks: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks  You must not have moved your .htaccess file over to the new host or need to regenerate it.

But you may also need to change URLs in the database from the old domain to the new IP/~username. See http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/

Comment: Thanks.It worked. I updated the urls in the database..its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to the problem here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/moved-wordpress-and-now-404-and-500-errors

If the problem remains, please use Ctrl+F5 to refresh your browser cache. Please make sure your permalinks in settings are using the same pattern.